# Using a Writer to push data to a SAXHandler

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a method which compares two XML documents (via streams) and writes the output to a Writer. The end result is that I want to then parse this into an in memory DOM document without creating an intermediary string, file or in memory structure.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to push the data from my writer into say a SAXHandler to create my DOM document.

I have it setup right now to just write the result to stdout (Note i1 and i2 are InputStream's for my original documents which I am comparing):

```
BufferedReader inputReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i1));
BufferedReader inputReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i2));
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
(new XMLCompare()).compare(inputReader1, "",inputReader2, "", writer);
```

So instead of writing the result of compare() to stdout I want to build a DOM document with it. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to do something like this - http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdom/converting-from-jdom-to-sax-supported-in-jdom-1.9-3.html?

Comment: I don't see how that helps -- maybe I am missing something though. I should also note that even though I say I want to convert to a DOM document. I really just want to go to a SAX handler because often DOM is too heavy and I want to skip this all-together. I was just using DOM as an example because is easy to understand.